# Auto convert True/False to 1/0 in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, syntax, odbc

I have MS SQL Server 2012 and are executing the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([isUpdated]) VALUES (False);
```

This gives the following error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'False'.
```

As I understand this is because there is no boolean type in the database, only bit field so only 0 or 1 is accepted. I've recently migrated to this database from the old outdated MS Access format and it accepted True/False in the SQL code. Here is my connection string:

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;Uid=myuser;Pwd=mypassword;
```

Is there some way to tell MS SQL Server to automatically treat True/False as 1/0?

I'm running a lot of old code and there is a lot of old SQL code that sends in True/False so if at all possible I would like to avoid having to update hundreds of lines of code manually. Is there something I can add to my connection string or a setting in the Server Management Studio program that I can change?

Comment: You  can update your line with an update query? `UPDATE yourtable set value = true where value = 1`, something like this. Or have you too much table?

Comment: no there isn't any way. You will have to replace true with 1 and false with 0 in all your scripts.

Comment: zaphod: ive got way too many tables, and i thought mssql didnt have a boolean field type? clausen: that sucks, are you 100% sure?

Comment: re: "only 0 or 1 is accepted [as a value for a `bit` column]" -  That's not quite true. SQL Server will also accept `INSERT INTO [TableName] ([isUpdated]) VALUES ('True')`. Unfortunately that doesn't help you all that much.